# How to combine a search phrase with a wildcard using Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am passing a search query to the Lucene QueryParser.Parse(string query) method, and then passing the result to Searcher.Search(Query query, int n).

A string of:

```
"system cleaner"
```

returns 1 hit.

A string of:

```
"system clean*"
```

or:

```
"system clean\*"
```

returns 0 hits.

How can I provide a search query that uses both a quoted phrase and a wildcard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QueryParser doesn't support that.  You can construct such a query using the [`SpanQuery` API](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/ddf/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_spans_1_1_span_query.html):

```
SpanQuery firstwordQuery = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("myField", "system"));
//Unfortunately, Lucene.Net doesn't have SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper...
SpanQuery secondwordQuery = new SpanRegexQuery(new Term("myField", "clean.*"));
SpanQuery[] spanClauses = new SpanQuery[] {firstwordQuery, secondwordQuery};
Query finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery(spanClauses, 0, true);
```

Comment: Nice example. Thanks!

Comment: For people working in JAVA Lucene v8 who came to this answer, you can use `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` with `WildcardQuery` as an alternative to `SpanRegexQuery`